# Need an equation to calculate the list of latitudes and longitudes of an off-nadir sensor with a given half angle

Tags: earth, geometry, sensor

I need a deterministic way to determine a list of latitude and longitudes of an off-nadir pointing sensor for a given half angle.  Below is a depiction of the problem.

[image: Sensor Pattern]

It isn't too hard to calculate the alpha intersections on the earth in the plane formed by the center of the earth, the vehicle position, and the boresite.  What I need is a general equations for the latitudes and longitudes that describe the sensor footprint. I can iterate to find them, but that is slow. I'm looking for a faster, deterministic method.

One approach I though of was a vehicle centric coordinate system where I step through an azimuth of 360 degrees and calculate the appropriate elevation angle (boresite angle from nadir plus alpha) but I don't have an equation to determine what the earth intersection (Lat/Long) would be for those azimuths and elevations.

Comment: Are you assuming spherical earth?

Comment: For now, spherical will work fine

Comment: Please? Anyone?  Anyone at all????